# Wiener process equality

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I came across such a problem that I can't solve

Prove that with probability $=1$ the equality

$$W_{t}^{4} = W_{t}^{3} - 3W_{t}^{2} +1$$ holds for infinite number of $t \ge 0$ but it doesn't hold for any $t \in \mathbb{Q}_{+}$. $W_{t}$ is a standard Wiener process.

What I did:
I computed expected value of both sides and end up with $$3t^2 = -3t+1$$ which has two solutions $\notin \mathbb{Q}$, one of which is positive. It makes me think that there may exist one $t$ satisfying conditions but no more than one.
Is there a mistake in my attempt?
If so, what is the solution of the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your paragraph "What I did" is way off base.

First, consider any real number $x$ solving $x^4=x^3-3x^2+1$, then the process $(W_t)$ is recurrent hence the (random) set $\{t\geqslant0\mid W_t=x\}$ is almost surely unbounded. This solves the first part of your question. However...

Consider $X$ the (non random) set of real numbers $x$ such that $x^4=x^3-3x^2+1$, then $X$ is finite hence, for every fixed $t$, $P(W_t\in X)=0$. By countable union, $P(\exists t\in\mathbb Q_+,\,W_t\in X)=0$, qed.

Comment: Sorry I understood the question that $t$ is fixed, and we measure probability that $P(W_t \in X)$, but it's obviously $0$ like you said. Is $W_t$ self recurrent for the same reason why a discrete Markov process on the integers line comes back to origin in finite steps with probability $1$?

Comment: @Jakobian Delete comment on main, then? Anyway, not every discrete Markov process on the integers line is recurrent but the simple random walk is, and indeed this can be used to show the linear Brownian motion is.